# Selenium Chrome get downloaded a pdf file in download directory but isfile reported that it is not a file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory": '/tmp/download-dir', "download.prompt_for_download": False, "download.directory_upgrade": True, "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(90)
driver.get('http://pericles.ipaustralia.gov.au/ols/epublish/content/olsPatentsPdfDownload?id=399')
```

A pdf file downloaded at /tmp/download-dir.  When I checked the file with os.path.isfile(downloadedPDF), it returns False.  When I try to get its size os.stat(downloadedPDF).st_size, it throws OSError.

```
for file in os.listdir('tmp/download-dir'):
  downloadedPDF = 'tmp/download-dir' + file
  if os.path.isfile(downloadedPDF):
    print('It is a file')
  else:
    print('It is not a file')
```

Comment: I run it in AWS Lambda.  The download path sets to /tmp/download-dir.  I confirmed the file appeared in the path before it checks by os.path.isfile.

Comment: Could the problem be that you are missing the initial ```/``` for the directory: ```for file in os.listdir('/tmp/download-dir'):``` and ```downloadedPDF = '/tmp/download-dir' + file```

Comment: I missed the / for the filename. Thank for so much.